Flat bones deforming mesh? How to fix?
Posing a manikin right now, and somehow one of the bones got flattened, which is deforming all the vertexes onto a single plane. How to fix?


Switch to Pose Mode, select the bones and hit ⎇ AltS to reset their scales.
